# How can I have / effect a default value for variable scoping when passed to a function in a module?

Tags: python, function, scoping

Consider the following, working code:

```python
from package import FancyClass
f = FancyClass()
f.read('fancy.file', scope=globals())
```

Is there any way that, from within `FancyClass.read`,
  I can set the default value for `scope` to be the caller's `global` scope?
My *guess* is no, but I'm curious about alternative approaches
  (e.g. setting the scope upon package import, …).

<sup>This is for [my research](http://github.com/vermiculus/ssa-tool), yet to be committed at the time of writing. I can upload an example use to gist if requested.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It's very magical and you should probably never use it, but it is possible in CPython:

test.py:

```
import a

FOO = "foobar"
a.foo()
```

a.py:

```
import inspect

def foo(scope=None):
    if scope is None:
        f, _, _, _, _, _ = inspect.stack()[1]
        scope = f.f_globals
    print scope["FOO"]
```

Output:

```
foobar
```